# How can I run a Javascript file step-by-step in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, typeerror

I am working on a .NET project in visual studio, and can't figure out a bug. I created an object and it has a set property. At this point it comes up with an uncaught TypeError. I would like to know at what point does the property take the undefined parameters.
If you do a Console Application you can run it step-by-step(line-by-line), and you can find out, wher did it go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Native Interop Debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/28/javascript-native-interop-debugging-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) feature of the Visual Studio if you are developing a Window Store Application. Use "Script Only" for better experience.

If you are working on a web site, AFAIK you can use the VS javascript debug feature only for IE. [Check out this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z959x58c.aspx).

You could also use the Developer Tools of the user agent (Hit F12 in any browser). You will find all the resources loaded from the server and you can put breakpoints inside the scripts. Some browsers support [Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) debugging too. [Here is an example of javascript debugging in google chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Hope it helps.